# Technical stop Flying Dubai to Christchurch

Tags: transit, transit-visas, australia

I will be flying from Johannesburg via Dubai to Christchurch with a technical stop in Sydney, do I need a Visa for this?

Comment: You're certain it's only a technical stop?  What are the airline and flight numbers?

Comment: Also, what is your citizenship?

Comment: @NateEldredge Emirates 412 flies Dubai-Sydney-Christchurch, with the same flight number throughout, the same kind of plane and a 1hr45m stop in Sydney. It could be that one. The Emirates booking website describes the itinerary as "one stop", whereas for another itinerary I found via Sydney, with different flight numbers and a 9hr wait in Sydney it says "one connection" and " Passengers on connecting flights will need to change aircraft."